# Several projects in one solution with cmake and visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with 5 projects in it, two libraries and three applications (that depend on the libraries). I would now like to migrate the build system to CMake (to also be able to compile under Linux).

I've already found out how to write a CMakeLists.txt for one project and create a .sln file out of it that compiles in VS. However, I can't find a solution to specify in a CMake file each individual projects and then automatically let CMake create a VS .sln with those 5 projects in it.

How do I have to structure my projects and CMakelists to accomplish this?

Comment: Its not that hard, you have to declare each library and each executable. it can be in separate subdirectories. I recommend looking at some open source projects and their CMake files. (for example [this](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For each library, call [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html), for each application call [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html).

Answer (score 3):

Every cmake call to `add_library` or `add_executable` creates a new project in your solution.