# How to get a VS solution with all the projects and solutions for single projects with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

TL;DR I basically want a modular solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196076/several-projects-in-one-solution-with-cmake-and-visual-studio). Not only one solution with everything in it, but also a solution for each executable alone.

---

In my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330271/cmake-project-organisation?noredirect=1#comment87732039_50330271) I wanted to know how I should split my CMakeLists.txt among different folders. Some folders contain code that will be a static library and some code will be executables or dynamic libraries that build on those static libraries.

Folder structure looks like this:

```
/path/to/base/
  CMakeLists.txt
  app1/
    <src files for app1>
    CMakeLists.txt
  app2/
    <src files for app2>
    CMakeLists.txt
  lib/
    <src files for lib>
    CMakeLists.txt
```

If I take the approach of having a `CMakeLists.txt` in the parent folder to all my libraries and executables and from the include all the directories I have the problem that when I generate VS projects/solutions that my projects for each target contains all the projects - not only the ones necessary for my intended target.

Contents of `CMakeLists.txt` in the base folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(app1)
add_subdirectory(app2)
```

and the `CMakeLists.txt` in the app1 folder (app2 is equivalent)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(app1)

add_executable(app1 <src of app1>)

target_link_libraries(app1 lib)
```

and `CMakeLists.txt` of lib:

```
add_library(lib <src of lib>)
```

If I run cmake on the `CMakeLists.txt` from base the solution contains all the projects. And even if I open just one of the projects; it also contains everything. VS project of app1 also builds app2 - which I don't want.

If I only run cmake on the `CMakeLists.txt` of app1 I get a solution which doesn't contain app2 but it also doesn't contain lib, because that's only mentioned for linking inside the cmake file and not as a target (it's in the base file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake will create a solution for each call to [`project`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/project.html), which will then include all the targets of the current directory and its subdirectories (regardless whether they were defined before or after the actual call to `project`).

Here's what a well-behaved CMake script should do: Each CMakeLists that you want to be able to act as a root of its own sub-tree within the larger project should start with a `cmake_minimum_required` call, followed by the `project` call. Writing `project` in a CMakeLists basically means: This is a fully self-contained component that can be built independently, even if you delete all the files from its parent directories. As such, it makes sense to have a separate solution for each such `project`.

With this in mind we can see why this doesn't work in your case: Your apps are not fully self-contained, they depend on *lib*. The solution to this is to write the build scripts for the apps as if *lib* was provided as a third-party component, with `find_package` calls and everything.
In the compound build, you already have a target for *lib*, so the script invoked by the `find_package` call should be made to short-circuit to using that target and only actually go scavenging the system if it cannot find that existing target.

Also read up on how [CMake's packaging system](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) works, which provides some automation to handle such cases pretty elegantly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When you say "... with `find_package` calls and everything". Could you elaborate what 'and everything' entails? I will start reading the link you provided.

Comment: @Philipp Just that you should not make any assumptions about *lib* that you wouldn't have if you weren't also its author. Treat it as you would any other third-party dependency that is not under your control.